# QWebView shows raw html in some cases

Tags: html, qt, qwebview

I'm using the following code.

```
QWebView *lpView = new QWebView(*%parent_widget%*);
lpView->load(QUrl(*%path_to_html%*));
```

With [some pages](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/learning/prevnext.html) it works just fine and shows the rendered page. And [on others](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf) it shows raw html.

I suspect that the issue is the content of html page but I can't pinpoint what exactly breaks the rendering in QWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with encoding. Pages that didn't load were in UTF-8 with BOM and QWebViewer expected plain UTF-8.